# About the coefficients in the Taylor series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given $$f(z)=(1-z)e^{z+\frac{z^2}{2}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n z^n,$$ the question was to determine which of the following statements are correct.

$1.\ a_n\in (-\infty,0]$

$2. \displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} |a_n| < 1$.

I tried to derive the Taylor expansion but it's complicated and not giving general formula for $a_n$.

Is there any other result/way which will be helpful here? Any hint could be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f'(z) = -z^2 e^{z+{z^2 \over 2}} = -z^2 e^z e^{z^2 \over 2}$. It is not hard to see (and prove by induction) that the Taylor series of $z^2 e^z e^{z^2 \over 2}$ has all non negative coefficients and so $a_n \le 0$ for all $n>1$.

The $z^2$ in the expression for $f'(z)$ above shows
that $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.

Since $f(1) = 0 = 1 + \sum_n a_n = 1-\sum_n |a_n|$, we
see that $\sum_n |a_n| = 1$.